# need help with a pdu unit installation

Tags: electrical, wiring, installation

so i recently been gift with a pdu from APC is an AP7864 this thing says that works with 120v/208v.3~ now the connector is a L21-220 wich has 5wire 4 poles, this thing is rated for 3 phase and a neutral and ground, i only have and standart 2 phase 1 neutral installation at home, my question is this possible to turn on this thing somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up one thing: most houses actually run as [Split-phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-phase_electric_power) which is single-phase, and a center-tap neutral. [Two-phase power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_electric_power) is a separate thing and basically obsolete.

---

Unfortunately, you can't connect a 3-phase device to single-phase power directly. I am not sure precisely what would happen, but I strongly suspect it would release the magic blue smoke (hint: this is bad).

You can get phase converters, these cost from a couple thousand to multiple thousands of dollars.

[image: Digital phase converter] [image: Rotary phase converter]

You'd be better off buying a single-phase PDU. Easier install, cheaper, and don't have a huge phase converter taking up a bunch of space.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data sheet this is a 3 phase 208V input. Normal house voltage in the U.S. is Single phase 240. So it wont work without spending $ to convert single phase to 3 phase this would cost as much as the unit itself or more. The product family info in the data sheet said it had a wide range of input and output values but did not show any conversion information. If you have the manual it may show if it can be converted to run on 120/240V.